# Trying to map the output of 2 different API calls based on select dropdown to one single table in React JS

Tags: reactjs, select, html-table

I have 2 select dropdows in which i select the username in one and the project name in the other. I need to display which user is mapped to which project in a table.
The requirement is:

1. I need to show one single user mapped to all different projects
2. I need to show all the users mapped to one single project

i need to get these both done in a single table, but these are 2 different select dropdown options.

As of now, i am ablw to individually map it to seperate tables.

I need to have a single handle function for both the select dropdows, so when i change in either, the result of the select which i clicked on should be shown in the table.

please help me out

[This is what i have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMhJC.png)